# getIntent() doesn't retrieve previous activity's intent and return null

Tags: android

I am trying to post in an ArrayList of strings from one activity to another when the option menu is pressed. However, when I try to `getIntent()` in the next page, it returns null value.

Option menu when item is selected code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if(item.getItemId()==2){
       ArrayList<String>data1=new ArrayList<>();
       data1.add("Hello");
       data1.add("bye");
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("dataList",data1);
       startActivity(i);
   }
    return true;
}
```

Retrieve Data Activity :

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("dataList");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
   lListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    lListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not `getIntent()` at Class creation (talking in programming level) but when the `Activity` is created, that means inside `onCreate(...)`. Same thing for the data as it's part of the `Intent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("dataList");
```

add this lines in oncreate

Answer (score 1):

Move this code into your `onCreate` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("dataList");
```

Intent does not exist at the point that you try to get it, it is being passed later in your activity's lifecycle. That is why you are getting `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> Check changes i have made in your code.. getIntent() should be called
>   inside oncreate...

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    //changes
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       ArrayList<String> data =            
       intent.getExtras().getStringArrayListExtra("dataList");
       //changes
       lListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lListView);
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
        lListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first set

```
 i.putStringArrayListExtra("dataList",data1);
```

Then call in **Oncreate()** section ;

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<String> data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("dataList");
```

Finally

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> data = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("dataList");

    lListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    lListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `i.putStringArrayListExtra("dataList", data1);` to set the `ArrayList` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try in the other Activity in onCreate():

```
ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dataList");
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("dataList");
```